# Twitter APP and Twitter API.. is there a way to create an app which works INSIDE twitter?

Tags: api, twitter

I'd like to ask if is there a way to create a very simple app that automatically retweets only one or two users of my following list. I don't want to use an external website or a desktop app to do it, nor a mobile one.. I'd like to just have an app in my twitter account settings that does it.
Is this impossible?
If it is possible, where should I write the code?
If it is impossible, and the app MUST be connected with a website, how do I make the website to be continuously checking in order to be "automatic"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't put it *in twitter*. Easiest way is to create web application (because you will have to authenticate yourself in order to access your twitter stream programmatically)

You don't have to be "continuously checking" - all you have to do is run your application few times a day - get tweets and retweet one. You can automate it by using CRON (on Linux webhosting) or Task Scheduler on a Windows machine.

Comment: thank you Brett, so basically I have to create a web application, which is a webpage that does it or a program running on a webserver?